# Condition to control multithreading connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops

I implemented a multithreading connection between a server and two clients, but when I start my program, the server starts an infinite loop. It is a problem because my server implements also a graphic interface that can't be run because it's blocked by this loop. I want to remedy, choosing a different condition to stop my cycle, instead using a `while(true)`cycle. 
Here is the code of my cycle:

```
public Socket attendi(){
    try {
       System.out.println("inizializzo il server");
       ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
       while(true){
           System.out.println("server pronto in ascolto");
           s = ss.accept(); //s is a global Socket object
           ThreadServer newConnection = new ThreadServer();
           newConnection.connect(s);
           System.out.println("connessione stabilita");
       }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   return s;
}
```

Can you recommend a good condition that will stop the cycle when there are no more clients attempting to connect to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to extend `Runnable`:

```
public class MyRunnable extends Runnable {

    public void run(){
        try {
           System.out.println("inizializzo il server");
           ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
           while(true){
               System.out.println("server pronto in ascolto");
               s = ss.accept(); //s is a global Socket object
               ThreadServer newConnection = new ThreadServer();
               newConnection.connect(s);
               System.out.println("connessione stabilita");

               handleConnection(s);
           }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then implement a daemon thread factory. Daemon threads will not prevent the application from terminating:

```
public class DaemonThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

    public Thread newThread( Runnable runnable ) {
        Thread thread = threadFactory.newThread(runnable);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Then create the thread using the thread factory:

```
ThreadFactory factory = new DaemonThreadFactory();
Thread thread = factory.newThread( new MyRunnable() );
thread.start();
```

Based on the code and description provided, it sounds to me like you're not actually running this in a separate thread.

Comment: In this way my loop will stop when I'll close my window, right? But my problem is that the window neither opens

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. Does this help a bit more? :)

Answer (score 1):

Start a new thread and put this logic inside the new thread so that your main thread will not be blocked.

Like this your main thread will simply start a new thread and continuue further program execution. And the new thread will do whatever you want to do (some blocking operation in your case), without blocking the main thread.

You can use Java's build in [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for the same. You need not to return `s` because it is global variable.  See below code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
       System.out.println("inizializzo il server");
       ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
       while(true){
           System.out.println("server pronto in ascolto");
           s = ss.accept(); //s is a global Socket object
           ThreadServer newConnection = new ThreadServer();
           newConnection.connect(s);
           System.out.println("connessione stabilita");
       }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
});

//Now program execution will continue and the new thread created will execute the logic you have placed in `run` method.
```

Comment: This would kick off a new thread, but you could still end up with a stuck thread when the window is closed.

Comment: No problem. But finally which solution you implemented, this one or one from andy's answer?